# GLM Error in R - Getting the message: "Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values"

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I am trying to assign a poisson distribution to the random component of a GLM in R, however I keep getting the message "Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values" when I try the following code:

```
normal.poisson.glm <- glm(Incidents ~ Temp, family=poisson(link=identity), data=O.Ring_Problems)
```

The formula works when I change "identity" to "log" or when I change "poisson" to "gaussian", but I can't figure out how to plug starting values in to make the formula. Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

My original dataframe is:

```
O.Ring_Problems <- data.frame(
"Temp" = c(53,56,57,63,66,67,67,67,68,69,70,70,70,70,72,73,75,75,76,76,78,79,80,81),
"Incidents" = c(3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Why use "identity" if you are fitting a Poisson distribution?

Comment: Maybe I misspoke, but I'm looking to have a Poisson regression model with a "normal" rather than "poisson" random component. For that, the family would be Poisson but the link would be identity, correct?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean by a 'Poisson regression with a "normal" rather than "poisson" random component'. 'a "normal" random component' sounds like an ordinary least-squares model to me. Maybe (??) you want a logarithmic *link function* (as in a typical Poisson model) with Gaussian errors? (`glm(..., family = gaussian(link = "log"))`)

Comment: Ah sorry about that - the last sentence is what I want. Basically my code works if the link is either poisson(link=log) or gaussian(link=identity), but it fails and gives the above error message when I try poisson(link=identity) or gaussian(link=log)